# Flex: What OpenSource Container Component should I use?

Tags: apache-flex, components

Please help me what container component I will use. Here is my problem, I have advance data grid with full of data about 300 by 300 row-column(data can be picture). Now I need a container that can zoom in/out, fit to screen capability and can drag around the component inside so that my data grid will be zoomable and dragable around the container(Easy for the user to read content inside my datagrid). Any suggestion for a container that fits on what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely have to add some functionality to AdvandedDataGrid to do that sort of stuff.  The grid only renders cells that are currently on screen (well, mostly) to achieve a decent  performance level.  If you enlarged your grid to show all cells and then embedded that into a container that managed scrolling, etc, it would likely be unacceptably slow.

But you could add event handlers directly to the grid to manage your new user gestures.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/wiki/ComponentList

Maybe the dragscrollCanvas container, combined with scaleX/scaleY  events on the datagrid in response to mousewheeel events for the zoom?

Not sure exactly what you need...

Answer (score -1):

you need to use a custom itemRenderer for your datagrid field. There are some great tutorials out there...
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/using_item_renderers/
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html (is a series of

And if you know what you are looking for then I'm sure that you can find the right itemRenderer for your datagrid.

Then using your custom component you can move it around, zoom,  etc.

If you are talking about the container that contains the datagrid checkout the flexlib mdi container. This container can have other windows inside of it then you can tile, cascade, fill, etc. This also supports dragging. 
example: http://www.returnundefined.com/flexmdi/explorer/
webpage: http://code.google.com/p/flexmdi/